# Detect whether a dataframe has a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a new method to parse a `DataFrame` into a Vincent-compatible format. This requires a standard `Index` (Vincent can't parse a `MultiIndex`).

Is there a way to detect whether a Pandas `DataFrame` has a `MultiIndex`?

```
In: type(frame)
Out: pandas.core.index.MultiIndex
```

I've tried:

```
In: if type(result.index) is 'pandas.core.index.MultiIndex':
        print True
    else:
        print False
Out: False
```

If I try without quotations I get:

```
NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
```

Any help appreciated.

(Once I have the `MultiIndex`, I'm then resetting the index and merging the two columns into a single string value for the presentation stage.)

Comment: `name 'pandas' is not defined` you should `import pandas` first!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` to check whether an object is a class (or its subclasses):

```
if isinstance(result.index, pandas.MultiIndex):
```

Comment: Works for me - this made me realise my error, as I have a habit of importing pandas as 'pd' for shorthand. This edited version worked for my script:

    if isinstance(result.index, pd.core.index.MultiIndex):

Comment: FWIW, at least as of version 0.24.1, you can use `if isinstance(result.index, pandas.MultiIndex):`

Comment: in pandas 0.24.2 use:

```if isinstance(result.keys(), pd.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex):```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `nlevels` to check how many levels there are:

```
df.index.nlevels 
df.columns.nlevels
```

If `nlevels > 1`, your dataframe certainly has multiple indices.

Comment: Note that `nlevels==1` is possible also for indices of type `pd.MultiIndex`. If the type matters, testing with `isinstance(df, pd.MultiIndex)` is the correct way.

Comment: This answer has the merit of being nicely aligned with Python's "duck typing" --- what matters to me is whether I have to deal with multiple levels or just one, not the specific instance. And it is just as fast if not faster than `isinstance()` on my machine.

Comment: When `df.index.nlevels = 1` and `df.columns.nlevels > 1`, `isinstance(df, pd.MultiIndex)` gives False. In other words, the accepted answer only works when there are multiple levels on the index, not if the multiple levels are only on the columns. I think this answer is the safest way to test.

Answer (score 7):

There's also

```
len(result.index.names) > 1
```

but it is considerably slower than either isinstance or type:

```
timeit(len(result.index.names) > 1)
The slowest run took 10.95 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 µs per loop
In [254]:

timeit(isinstance(result.index, pd.MultiIndex))
The slowest run took 30.53 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 177 ns per loop
In [252]:

)
timeit(type(result.index) == pd.MultiIndex)
The slowest run took 22.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 200 ns per loop
```

Comment: You should note that the len(result.index.names) > 1 is in micro seconds and the others are in nano seconds, so len actual takes 1,120 ns.

Comment: Arrgh! Thankyou @JohnCEarls, those pesky friendly unit converters keep catching my eyes out (boost unittest does something similar).

Comment: Can a MultiIndex not have just one level?

Comment: Why not `df.index.nlevels`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shortest way is `if type(result.index)==pd.MultiIndex:`