# How do I check if a pandas dataFrame.index is a multiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame object, and I want to check if its index field is a multiIndex, or if the index is "length one". For instance:

```
def myFunction(self, dataFrame):
    if is_multi_index(dataFrame):
        dostuff()

@staticmethod
def is_multi_index(dataFrame):
    # how to code?
```

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081042/detect-whether-a-dataframe-has-a-multiindex). Do your research first.

Comment: Thanks for the proper redirect, but please don't resort to rudeness.